# Formatting QR Codes in HTML emails using the <pre> tag

Tags: html, email, qr-code

I'm writing an online booking system that sends a QR code as part of a confirmation email / electronic ticket.

The email is in HTML format and, because many people turn off images in their email client, I'm investigating displaying the QR Code in the body of the message using the `<pre>` tag.

This way the QR Code will display regardless of the email client setting on displaying images or not.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<pre style="font-family: 'Lucida Console', Monaco, monospace; font-size: 8px; font-weight: 900; padding: 0; letter-spacing: 0; line-height: 8px; ">



     ███████  █  █ ███████     
     █     █ █  █  █     █     
     █ ███ █  █    █ ███ █     
     █ ███ █ █  █  █ ███ █     
     █ ███ █   ███ █ ███ █     
     █     █ ███ █ █     █     
     ███████ █ █ █ ███████     
               ███             
     █████ ████  ██ █ █ █      
     █ █ █   ██  █  █  █       
     █ █  ███████ █  █ █
     ██  █   ██     ██ ███     
      ███  █    █ █  █ ██      
             █  ████  █        
     ███████ █ █ █ ██    █     
     █     █   █████  █        
     █ ███ █ ██  █  █  █       
     █ ███ █ ██  █  █  █       
     █ ███ █ ██ █ █  ███       
     █     █ ███    ██ ██      
     ███████ ████ █  ███       



</pre>
```

This is almost looking okay in Outlook, but in gmail it looks terrible:

[image: pre tag in email reader]

I have a few questions and I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction:

1. Is there a trick to get gmail to observe the line height?
2. Is there a better font to use? I'm using 'Lucida Console' which gives me a 8px x 6px rectangle but I ideally want a monospace font that is square.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I gave up on trying to represent a QR code as HTML. There were too many problems that could not be overcome, including the fact that chrome didn't like printing background colours in tables so the qrcode wouldn't print.

However, I *did* manage to embed the image into the email so it showed up in outlook and gmail without the user having to download an image.

In case someone else is trying to embed QR Codes (or other images) into emails so that they show immediately, I'll put my solution here.

The important thing is to use a linked resource and reference it correctly in your HTML:

```
...
<p><img src=""cid:{0}"" alt=""booking barcode"" /><br></p>
...
```

I used the following references:

```
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net.Mime;
```

When creating my email:

```
public class BookingConfirmation : MailMessage
{
    public BookingConfirmation( ... )
    {
        To.Add( ... );
        Subject = "...";

        // create some html for the email
        var html = String.Format(
        @"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"" 
        ""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\"">
        <html xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"">
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv=""Content-Type"" content=""text/html; charset=utf-8"" />
        <meta name=""viewport"" content=""width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"" />
        <title>My Title</title>
        </head>
        <body style=""font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px;"">
        <p><img src=""cid:{0}"" alt=""booking barcode"" /><br></p>
        </body>
        </html>","myuniqueid1234" );

        // create an html view
        var htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(html, 
                                                                   Encoding.UTF8, 
                                                                   MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);

        // get an image as a memory stream
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        var qrCodeImage =  ... however you want to access your image ...;
        qrCodeImage .Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        memoryStream.Position = 0;

        // add it as a linked resource to the alternate view
        var linkedImage = new LinkedResource(memoryStream, MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg)
        {
            ContentId = "myuniqueid1234" // this needs to match for <img src=""cid:{0}""
        }; 

        // add the linked resource to the html format alternate view
        htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(linkedImage) ;
        AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);
    }
}
```

Comment: What type is qrCodeImage variable?

Comment: System.Drawing.Image  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.save?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 2):

This is a rather good idea!

Your problem is mostly problems with mail program. You should have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9247788/817695), the problem is related to yours. You might have to use table-cells (with a black background?).

Answer (score 0):

If some one looking for same solution.

I've made python script for generation in unicode good shaped square QR using one simbol for two lines:

qr.py:

```
import sys
import qrcode

input_data = sys.argv[1]

qr = qrcode.QRCode(
        version=1,
        box_size=1,
        border=5)
qr.add_data(input_data)
qr.make(fit=True)
img = qr.make_image(fill='black', back_color='white')

pixels = img.load() 
width, height = img.size

all_pixels = []

qr_str = ''

for y in range(height):

    if y % 2 == 0:
        line = ''
        for x in range(width):

            # Draw two lines at once
            if y % 2 == 0:
                
                # First line pixel
                first_pixel = pixels[x, y]
                
                # Second line pixel
                if y + 1 != height:
                    second_pixel = pixels[x, y + 1]
                else:
                    second_pixel = 255
                
                # Choose right unicode char
                if first_pixel > 0 and second_pixel > 0:
                    line += ' '
                
                if first_pixel == 0 and second_pixel > 0:
                    line += '▀'

                if first_pixel > 0 and second_pixel == 0:
                    line += '▄'

                if first_pixel == 0 and second_pixel == 0:
                    line += '█'

        qr_str += '\n' + line

print(qr_str)
```

And usage:

```
pip3 install pillow
pip3 install qrcode

python3 qr.py https://google.com



     ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄ ▄▄ ▄▄ ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄
     █ ▄▄▄ █  ▄█▀▄▀▄ ▀ █ ▄▄▄ █
     █ ███ █ █▄ ▄▄ ▄▄█ █ ███ █
     █▄▄▄▄▄█ █ █▀▄ ▄ █ █▄▄▄▄▄█
     ▄   ▄ ▄▄██  ▀█  ▀▄▄▄▄▄  ▄
     ▄▄▄█▄▄▄ █▄▀▄▄▀▀██ ▄▄██▄▀
     █ █ ▄▄▄▄▀█▄  ▄█▄ ▄██ ▄██▄
     ▀▀ ▀▀▀▄ ██▀▄█▄▄█  ▄▄█▄▄▀
     ▄▄ ██▄▄█  ▄▀▄█ ▀▄▄███▄█▀
     ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄ █ █  ▀▀ █ ▄ █
     █ ▄▄▄ █ ▄▄▀▄▀▄█ █▄▄▄███▀█
     █ ███ █  ██▄█▄▄  ██▀ ▄▀█▀
     █▄▄▄▄▄█ ▄ █▀▄█ █ ▄ ▀▀▀██▄
```